Construct an ordered sequence where larger and alphabetically preceding subsequences have higher summations when the elements of the subseq are added
Given $n$, does there exist an ordered sequence of (real) numbers $\{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n\}$ such that

The ordering is such that we only consider subsequences of the form $(x_{i_1}, \cdots, x_{i_j})$ where $i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_r$ for all $1 \leq r \leq n$.

A larger subsequence must always have a larger sum: $\displaystyle \sum_{j \in S} x_j > \displaystyle \sum_{k \in T} x_k \iff |S| > |T|$ where $S, T \subseteq \{1,2, \cdots, n\}$.

Suppose $(x_{i_1}, \cdots, x_{i_r})$ and $(x_{j_1}, \cdots, x_{j_r})$ are two ordered sequences of the same size. The sequence that alphabetically precedes the other sequence (where the ordering is based on the subscript) will have a higher sum (when the elements are added). For example, $(x_1,x_9,x_{10})$ will produce a higher sum than $(x_2,x_7,x_8)$. In the same vein, $x_1 > x_2 > \cdots > x_n$.


For $n = 3$, the chain of inequalities will be: $x_1+x_2+x_3 > x_1+x_2 > x_1 + x_3 > x_2 + x_3 > x_1 > x_2 > x_3$. The existence of such a seq. can be demonstrated by $(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (4,3,2)$.
Can we generalize this for all $n$, either by constructing such sequences or merely by showing the existence (without explicitly assigning values of the $x_is$)?

Consider
$$
x_i = 1+ 2^{-i}\epsilon,
$$
where $0< \epsilon < 1$. This structure ensures that for any $S$, we have
$$
|S| < \sum_{i\in S} x_i < |S| +1,
$$
where the first inequality is trivial and the second inequality follows from
$$
\sum_{i\in S} 2^{-i} \epsilon \le \left( \frac12 + \frac14 + \cdots + \frac1{2^n} \right) \epsilon < \epsilon <1.
$$
It follows that the second condition is satisfied. The third condition is also satisfied. To see this, say $i_1=j_1,\ldots,i_{k-1} = j_{k-1}$, and $i_k < j_k$. Then,
$$
2^{-i_k} + 2^{-i_{k+1}} + \cdots +2^{-i_r} > 2^{-i_k} > \sum_{l=j_k}^n 2^{-l} > 2^{-j_k} + 2^{-j_{k+1}}+\cdots+2^{-j_r}.
$$

Thoughts on what other conditions we could use apart from $f(1) + f(2) + \ldots + f(n)  < N$  and  $f(a) > f(a+1) + f(a+2) + \ldots + f(n)$?

@CalvinLin Not sure, those seem like the most natural conditions that ensure both conditions in the OP are satisfied. The specific sequence in my answer is clearly in line with these conditions. I have thought about this problem a couple of years ago and came up with the above solution.

Thanks. I agree that these conditions are most natural. $\quad$ It somewhat irks me that OP's example doesn't neatly satisfy these conditions, as they then can't generalize from there. It could be thought of as $(2+2, 2+1, 2+0)$ and then painfully explain why it satisfies conditions 2 and 3.

Let $ x_i = N + f(i)$.
Lemma: To satisfy the conditions, it is sufficient (thought not necessary) to have

$ N > 0 $
$f(i) > 0 $
$f(1) + f(2) + \ldots + f(n)  < N$.
$\forall a < n$, $f(a) > f(a+1) + f(a+2) + \ldots + f(n)$.

Note: The last condition implies that $f(i)$ will be a decreasing function, and thus $x_1 > x_2 > x_3 > \ldots > x_n$
Proof:
Condition 2: If $|S| = k$, then $ kN <  \sum_{s \in S } x_s < (k+1) N$. So a larger subsequence will have a larger sum.
Condition 3: For $|S| = |T| = k$ and $S < T $, let $ a $ be the smallest index in $S$ but not in $T$. Then,
$$ \begin{array}{  l l l l l l l }  
\sum_{s \in S } x_S & =  kN  & + \sum_{s \in [a-1]} f(s) & + f(a)  &  + \sum_{s \in [n] \backslash [a]} f(s)  \\
&  >  kN  & +  \sum_{t \in [a-1]} f(t)  & +  f(a+1) + f(a+2) + \ldots + f(n)  & + 0\\
& \geq \sum_{ t \in T } x_t . \end{array}$$
Corollary: $x_i = n(2^n + 1) +  2^{n-i+1}$ and $ x_i = n^n + n^{n-i}$ both work.
